# Group same muscles exercise

Tags: exercise, exercise-frequency

Which is better for gaining bigger muscles.
To group all exercises for the same muscle or distribute over the whole day

in other words

**Option 1 :**

First Chest exercise 1 then Bi ex 1 then Tri ex 1

Then Chest exercise 2 then Bi ex 2 then Tri ex 2

Then Chest exercise 3 then Bi ex 3 then Tri ex 3

**Option 2 :**

First Chest exercise 1 then Chest exercise 2 then Chest exercise 3

Then Bi ex 1 then Bi ex 2 then Bi ex 3

Then Tri ex 1 then Tri ex 2 then Tri ex 3

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is a "better" in this. Changing your workout routine once in a while will always give the best results, so you could be doing option 1 for a few weeks and transition into option 2 for the next weeks.

Comment: I agree with @MJB here. Looking for a "best alternative" in fitness isn't really something that gets you anywhere, unless we're talking about options with huge differences. Pick whichever feels best, try it for a few months, and measure your progress. Then make an evaluation; is it worth it to try the other alternative, or are you happy where you are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main factor for muscle hypertrophy is volume. It doesn't matter which order you use in your workouts while training as long as your muscles are getting sufficient stimulus for growth.

As @mjb in comments as said, you there is no method which is 'better' here. I'd like to repeat the same thing.

However, the option 2 is the better split for someone who wants to optimize their workout since it will allow the muscle to relax a bit before you pound it with another exercise after your first one.

The issue, however with the option 2 is that you will not get a big pump, but as long as the volume remains the same, it won't matter.